# given two sentences S1,S2 ; task is to find Words in S1 but not in S2

Tags: python

problem Statement :- given two sentences S1,S2 ; task is to find Words in S1 but not in S2

```
def string_features(s, f):
        s=s.lower()
        s1=set(s.split())
        f=f.lower()
        s2=set(f.split())
        s4=s1-s2
        s4_list=list(s4)
        s5=s2-s1
        s5_list=list(s5)
    
        for i in s4_list:
             if i.upper() in s:     
                 s4_list.remove(i)
                 s4_list.append(i.upper())
        print(f"Words in S1 but not in S2 are : {s4_list}")
            
               
string_features(s="the first column F will contain only 5 uniques values",
                f="the second column S will contain only 3 uniques values")
```

with this my expected out put should be ['first','F','5']; but i am getting
['f', 'first', '5']. 'f' is still in lower case whereas it should be 'F' in upper case.

Comment: Once you called `.lower()`, it lowercased whole string. What else did you expect?

Comment: Don't lower s and f before generating the set of split values. Iterate through each item in S1 and if item.lower() it is not in S2.lower(), add item to your list.

Comment: f= "the second column S will contain only 3 uniques values"
s2=f.split()

s3=[] # Empty List
s="the first column F will contain only 5 uniques values"
s1=s.split()

for item in s2:
    if item.lower is not in s1.lower() ## getting error as list doesn't have lower() function and i am converting the string into. a list with .split()

Comment: Your error lies in for loop. You are changing the list itself while iterating through it. So your logic is not perfect in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_features(s, f):
        s=s.lower()
        sen1 = s.split()
    
        f=f.lower()
        sen2 = f.split()
  
        group = []
        test = list(set(sen1).symmetric_difference(set(sen2)))

        for i in test:
            for x in sen1:
                if i == x:
                    group.append(i)

        print(f"Words in S1 but not in S2 are : {group}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to have the correct case, then you need to preserve the original casing.

```
def string_features(s, f):
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(s.split()) if x.lower() not in f.lower().split()]


string_features(s="the first column F will contain only 5 uniques values",f="the second column S will contain only 3 uniques values")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `lower()` when you want case sensitive result? You lowercased the whole string at the beginning, then there are no uppercase letters in s, which make the last part of your code useless. In fact, just removing `lower()` will make your code work.

As *set* is unordered collection, if you want to preserve the reading order, you may want to use a for loop to iterate the string or do it with list comprehension.

```
def string_diff(s1, s2):
    diff = list(set(s1.split()) - set(s2.split()))
    diff2 = [c1 for c1 in s1.split() if c1 not in s2.split()]
    print(f"Words in S1 but not in S2 are : {diff}")
    print(f"Words in S1 but not in S2 are : {diff2}")

s1 = "the first column F will contain only 5 uniques values"
s2 = "the second column S will contain only 3 uniques values"
string_diff(s1, s2)
```

Output:

```
Words in S1 but not in S2 are : ['5', 'first', 'F']
Words in S1 but not in S2 are : ['first', 'F', '5']
```